# OpenCV identifier "Tracker" is undefined

Tags: c++, opencv

i'm using OpenCV 3.2 and trying to compile the following code using Visual studio 2013:

```
#include <opencv2/core/utility.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>


#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap;
    Mat frame;
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 15);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('B', 'G', 'R', '3'));
    cap = VideoCapture(0);
    Ptr<Tracker> tracker = Tracker::create("KCF");
    while (1){
        cap.read(frame);
        imshow("TEST", frame);
        waitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it tells me that tracker is undefined.i'm trying to use the example from [Here.](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d0a/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.html)
the opencv2/tracking.hpp used there did not exist in my include directory so i added some files to fix including problems(required files were feature.hpp,onlineMIL.hpp,onlineBoosting.hpp,tracking.hpp. copied from opencv github)
 but still VS tells me that Tracker is undefined

Answer (score 2):

Opencv had moved all these extension librarys to Opencv-contrib when the Version 3.0  published, you can install from the github website:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib
please be care for choose the version about this Repository .